# Creating video from stream bitmap in android

Tags: android, video, bitmap

I have bitmaps i want to create video by sequence of bitmap in android.

My application receives a sequence of images (BitmapImage) from an external device with rate 10 fps.

I need to create an avi file from this images and then, save it on filesystem. How can I obtain this result? Are there any Android libraries can I use for this purpose?

Please Help

Comment: Try with the JavaCV project : https://code.google.com/p/javacv/.

Comment: Did you solved this?facing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late here, but yes there is a library for this. You can find it here: [opencv for android](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/). To integrate it with your android project, follow the instructions under `Quick Start for OpenCV and FFmpeg`. The best part about this library is all of the JNI wrapping is done for you. Although there is lack of documentation, there are a few links to similar projects using this library which you can find [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javacv/9PbvoXHTw-s). Hope this helps.